# Android - setImageBitmap(bmp) returns null after creating a video thumbnail

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, video-thumbnails

I'm using the `ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail()` function for years, but all of a sudden I don't understand why it stopped working. I have a video path like this (got after compressing it with VideoCompressor library):

```
 /storage/emulated/0/com.xscoder.appname/media/videos/VIDEO_20200918_145357.mp4
```

which is my `videoToSendURL` variable.

So I use the following code to display my video's thumbnail:

```
Bitmap thumb = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(videoToSendURL, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
    if (thumb != null) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Thumb: " + thumb.getByteCount());
        myImageView.setImageBitmap(thumb);
    } else { Log.i("Something went wrong."); }
```

The Logcat prints out:

```
THUMB: 294912
```

But the app crashes and I get the following FATAL EXCEPTION:

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap)' on a null object reference
```

I assume my `thumb` Bitmap is not null since the Logcat returns its byteCount data, and I know that `myImg` is not null, I've declared it in onCreate().

**-- UPDATE --**

What I really need to do is to create a video thumbnail to upload it to my server, so here's what code I use:

**External VideCompressor class**, the code resides in **public class XServerSDK extends Application {}**

```
public static class VideoCompressor extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
      @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
      Context ctx;
      VideoCompressor(Context context){ ctx = context; }

      @Override protected void onPreExecute() {
         super.onPreExecute();
         showHUD(ctx);
         Toast.makeText(ctx, "Compressing Video...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      }

      @Override
      protected String doInBackground(String... paths) {
         String filePath = null;
         try { filePath = KplCompressor.with(ctx).compressVideo(paths[0], paths[1]);
         } catch (URISyntaxException e) { e.printStackTrace();
            Log.i(TAG, "ERROR ON VIDEO COMPRESSOR: " + e.getMessage());
         }
         return  filePath;
      }
      @Override
      protected void onPostExecute(String compressedFilePath) {
         super.onPostExecute(compressedFilePath);

         File imageFile = new File(compressedFilePath);
         float length = imageFile.length() / 1024f; // Size in KB
         String videoSize;
         if(length >= 1024) { videoSize = length / 1024f + " MB";
         } else { videoSize = length + " KB"; }

         videoToSendURL = compressedFilePath;
         Log.i(TAG, "COMPRESSED VIDEO -> URL: " + videoToSendURL + " -> SIZE: " + videoSize);

        // HERE I CALL MY FUNCTION THAT'S IN MY Messages ACTIVITY
        new Messages().uploadFiles();

      }
   }
```

In the **Messages** Activity:

```
void uploadFiles() {
      // Video
        XSUploadFile(videoToSendURL, "video.mp4", (Activity)ctx, new XServerSDK.XSFileHandler() {
        @Override public void done(final String vidURL, String e) {
            if (vidURL != null) {
                Log.i(TAG, "VIDEO URL: " + vidURL);
                // Create VideoThumbnail
                 Bitmap thumb = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(videoToSendURL, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
                  if (thumb != null) {
                      Log.i(TAG, "videoToSendURL: " + videoToSendURL);
                      Log.i(TAG, "THUMB: " + thumb.getByteCount());
                      
                      // VideoThumb
                      String imgPath = getFilePathFromURI(getImageUri(thumb, ctx), ctx);
                      Log.i(TAG, "imgPath: " + imgPath);
                      XSUploadFile(imgPath, "image.jpg", (Activity) ctx, new XServerSDK.XSFileHandler() { @Override public void done(final String thumbURL, String e) { 
        if (thumbURL != null) { 
            Log.i(TAG, "VIDEO THUMB URL: " + thumbURL);
            if (vidURL.contains("upload_max_filesize")) {
                hideHUD();   
                simpleAlert("The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive and cannot be uploaded.", ctx);
           } else { 
              fileType = "video"; 
              sendMessage(thumbURL, vidURL, "", "");
           } 
           // error
           } else { hideHUD(); simpleAlert(e, ctx);
    }}});// ./ XSUploadFile
        
    } else { hideHUD(); simpleAlert("Something went wrong, try again.", ctx); }
    
      // error
      } else { hideHUD(); simpleAlert(e, ctx); }
    }});// ./ XSUploadFile
}
```

Here's my code to get a real Path from Uri:

```
//-----------------------------------------------
   // MARK - GET URI OF A STORED IMAGE
   //-----------------------------------------------
   public static Uri getImageUri(Bitmap bm, Context ctx) {
      ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
      String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(ctx.getContentResolver(), bm, "image", null);
      return Uri.parse(path);
   }


   //-----------------------------------------------
   // MARK - GET REAL PATH FROM URI
   //-----------------------------------------------
   public static String getFilePathFromURI(Uri uri, Context ctx) {
      @SuppressLint("Recycle")
      Cursor cursor = ctx.getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
      assert cursor != null;
      cursor.moveToFirst();
      int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
      return cursor.getString(idx);
   }
```

And finally, the Fatal exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.ContentResolver android.content.Context.getContentResolver()' on a null object reference
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.getContentResolver(ContextWrapper.java:103)
        at com.xscoder.hi.XServerSDK.getImageUri(XServerSDK.java:1253)
        at com.xscoder.hi.Messages$16.done(Messages.java:1403)
```

So, in this case, the code crashes when it gets to:

```
 String imgPath = getFilePathFromURI(getImageUri(thumb, ctx), ctx);
```

It never happened before, maybe it's because I'm calling the `uploadFiles()` function from the `VideoCompressor` class?

Comment: Can you share the rest of the stacktrace? Also, if you go to the path specified, is there a file there?

Comment: Check if the file exists, check if the storage permission is granted

Comment: `myImageView` is `null`, apparently. When you get a `NullPointerException`, the receiver is `null`, and for a call to `ImageView.setImageBitmap()`, the receiver is the `ImageView`.

Comment: Have you used `findVIewById()` for `imageView`?

Comment: Thanks to all your comments, myImg is not null, the video URL is the one I’ve posted and it’s stored in my device Internal Storage :( Maybe it’s because I call that function from the VideoCompressor class, onPostExecute(), since it’s another public class?

Comment: I've posted the entire code and a new fatal expectation, hope this helps

Comment: Delete `getFilePathFromURI()`. Also, in your `getImageUri()`, `ctx` is pointing to an invalid `Context` apparently, and your `ByteArrayOutputStream` is completely pointless. If your objective is to write the `Bitmap` to a file, create a `FileOutputStream` on your desired file, then call `compress()` on the `Bitmap`, supplying that `FileOutputStream`.

Comment: **getFilePathFromURI()** has ctx because I call it from my Messages Activity, where I've declared a **Context ctx = this;** variable